# R Equilibrium FX using VEC or Behavioural Equilibrium Exchange Rate (BEER)

Tags: time-series, programming

I dont have much experience with R.

I would like to do create model for FX Equlibrium using VEC or BEER.
I already know what variables I want to use in model:

- trade differential between UK and the US
- interest rate differential
- inflation rate differential
- constant a

I got data but not sure now to calculate coefficients and variable with model.
What library methods I can use, do you know about any example I could look into regarding VEC, BEER in R Studio?

Comment: Try to read about the model first. Then ask the questions you have.